# Response received on rendering jsreport with phantom-pdf is displaying UTF characters

Tags: angularjs

> Following is the code used to render the pdf report

`

```
exports.renderReport_ICE = function(req, res){
     var finalReports = req.body.finalreports;
     var reportType = req.body.reporttype;
     var shortId;
     if(reportType == "html") shortId = "rkE973-5l";
     else shortId = "H1Orcdvhg";
     var client = require("jsreport-client")("http://"+IP+":3001/");
         client.render({
             template: {
                shortid: shortId,
                recipe: reportType,
                engine: "handlebars"
             },
             data: {
                "overallstatus": finalReports.overallstatus,
                "rows": finalReports.rows
             }
         }, function(err, response) {
         if (err) {
             console.log('error when trying to render report:', err);
         }
         else{
             response.pipe(res);
         }
    });
}
```

`

> My angular code is,

`

```
reportService.renderReport_ICE(finalReports, reportType)
.then(function(data1) {
     var path = "/specificreports";
     openWindow = 0;
     if(openWindow == 0)
     {
         var myWindow = window.open();
         myWindow.document.write(data1);
     }
     openWindow++;
     $('.formatpdfbrwsrexport').remove();
},
function(error) {
     console.log("Error-------"+error);
})
```

`

> Following is the UTF displayed in the browser

%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��) /Creator (��) /Producer (��Qt 4.8.4 (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)) /CreationDate (D:20170328144424+05'30') >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /SA true /SM 0.02 /ca 1.0 /CA 1.0 /AIS false /SMask /None>> endobj 4 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] endobj 5 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Contents 8 0 R /Resources 10 0 R /Annots 11 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 595 842] >> endobj 10 0 obj << /ColorSpace << /PCSp 4 0 R /CSp /DeviceRGB /CSpg /DeviceGray >> /ExtGState << /GSa 3 0 R >> /Pattern << >> /Font << /F6 6 0 R /F7 7 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 11 0 obj [ ] endobj 8 0 obj << /Length 9 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream x��[�n�6���+x.��CR� ��l�)�C� �z(z(����͢����%-ڢ�Y���i����%��p�=�gH����_������O�>

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, what i did to overcome was to call the response in my controller. I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPdf([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
    { var theresult = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<byte[]>("./pdf.js", requestUri);
        return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(theresult), "application/pdf");
}
```

Where: pdf.js is the name of your js file hat has the jsreport code.
Instruction to add node services in link below.

I referenced form this link:
http://neil.red/coding/export-html-to-pdf-in-dot-net-core/

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.
But for me it is solved, when i changed post request parameter "Response-Type" to Array buffer and in the controller i used "URL.createObjectURL()" function to get the pdf template.